# Count child pages in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index `test` with documents like:

```
POST /test/page/a
{
  "Id": "a",
  "Parent": "0"
}

POST /test/page/b
{
  "Id": "b",
  "Parent": "a"
}

POST /test/page/c
{
  "Id": "c",
  "Parent": "a"
}

POST /test/page/d
{
  "Id": "d",
  "Parent": "c"
}
```

That is, in a logical `page` hierarchy looking like this:

```
0 (non existant)
|
`- a
   |
   > b
   |
   ` c
     |
     ` d
```

I can find all `page`s with `Parent` equal to `a`. I just:

```
POST /test/page/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "Parent": "a"
    }
  }
}
```

The answer (abbreviated):

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "page",
        "_id": "b",
        "_source": {
          "Id": "b",
          "Parent": "a"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "page",
        "_id": "c",
        "_source": {
          "Id": "c",
          "Parent": "a"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, on the client side, I can construct a tree view of the root element, and their direct children.

But, I also want to know the number of direct children to the (just listed) children.

I'd like an answer similar to:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "page",
        "_id": "b",
        "_source": {
          "Id": "b",
          "Parent": "a"
        },
        "_numberOfChildren": 1
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "page",
        "_id": "c",
        "_source": {
          "Id": "c",
          "Parent": "a"
        },
        "_numberOfChildren": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like ES to count the `_numberOfChildren` dynamically, in some kind of "sub query".

Is the answer perhaps an aggregation?

Maybe https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation.html ?

Comment: You are trying to use Elasticsearch in a way that's not supposed to be used in. The relationships you showed are sql like and ES doesn't know this in this form. You need [parent/child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child.html) from Elasticsearch to attempt this kind of functionality in only one query. What you are looking for is not available in only one query and without changing the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you do not have many items:

You can retrieve the information using only one query:

```
GET /test/page/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "Parent": "0"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "numberOfChildren": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Parent",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the response, `hits.hits` will contains the children of `0`.

For each node you will have its number of children in `aggregations.numberOfChildren.buckets` with this structure:

```
{
    "key": [page id],
    "doc_count": [number of children for this page]
}
```

Example response:

```
{
  ...
    "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "page",
        "_id": "a",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Id": "a",
          "Parent": "0"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "numberOfChildren": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "0",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "a",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "c",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Please not that:

- If the page does not have any hildren, it is not in the list.
- You have the number of children for all parents, not only the direct
  childs of `0`, thus it will break if you have many items (too many
  buckets).

#### If you have many items:

Easiest way is to use two queries:

```
GET /test/page/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "Parent": "0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will have 0's direct children in `hits.hits`.

Second query:

```
GET /test/page/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "Parent": [
            "a" // list 0's direct children ids
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "numberOfChildren": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Parent",
        "size": 0,
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will have the number of children of 0's direct children in `aggregations.numberOfChildrens.buckets`

You may also be able to use scripts, but I am not sure that they can work in this situation.

Parent-child relationship will not help you since parents and children cannot be of the same type.

Comment: Thanks, so aggregations can not be "filtered" in this way? In other words the aggregate will just return "all nodes children count" regardless of which node I am querying?

Comment: Would a nested aggregation solve anything? Like Betto86 did, but I could not really understand ...

Comment: Yes for your first question, no for the second:

What you want to achieve requires to read the data twice, first to get the direct children of the root, second to compute the number of children for those pages. 

Reading the data twice is not something that Elasticsearch do. If you want to save some bandwidth you may be able to use a custom scripted aggregation that computes those counters and only return the one you are interested in. It would be only one query, but a huge one (both in CPU and memory).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you are searching for:

I've tried to insert same elements:

```
PUT /tmp_index/doc/1
{
    "id": "a",
    "parent": "0"
}

PUT /tmp_index/doc/2
{
    "id": "b",
    "parent": "a"
}

PUT /tmp_index/doc/3
{
    "id": "c",
    "parent": "a"
}

PUT /tmp_index/doc/4
{
    "id": "d",
    "parent": "c"
}
```

With a nested aggregation like this:

```
POST /tmp_index/_search?pretty
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "aggs": {
      "group_by_first": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "parent",
             "size" : 0
         },
         "aggs": {
            "group_by_second": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "id",
                  "size" : 0
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You get this result:

```
{
           "key": "a",
           "doc_count": 2,
           "group_by_second": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "b",
                    "doc_count": 1
                 },
                 {
                    "key": "c",
                    "doc_count": 1
                 }
              ]
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "0",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "group_by_second": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "a",
                    "doc_count": 1
                 }
              ]
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "c",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "group_by_second": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "d",
                    "doc_count": 1
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
```

Comment: Can I using this type of query get the following back: `"0" have these children, and those children have x children each`

Answer (score 0):

[Updated]

I'm not sure if you can achieve it all in one query.

I needed something similar and ended up using `msearch` for the follow-up query.

```
POST /test/_msearch
{}
{"query" : {"term" : {"Parent": "c"}}}, "size" : 0}
{}
{"query" : {"term" : {"Parent": "d"}}}, "size" : 0}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really what I wanted ... I'll clarify a bit

Comment: Now, I edited the question to further clarify what the problem is. Thanks